# How to access a Global variable in React JS functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, global

I have a global variable in the window object in a functional React component.

[image]

It's Global --> Designer --> nodes --> NODE_FORM --> props --> dataSource deep.
How can I access it in my functional component?

Answer (score 2):

Global variables are bad design within react. Use Context instead
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 0):

Y would you? It doesnt make any sense. Alot of anti patterns at onces.
But the way of doing It Is

```
Global === Window
```

```
const Comp = props => { 

  const [get, set]= React.useState("");
  React.useEffect(()=>{
set(window.Designer.nodes.NODE_FROM.dataSource);

},[window.Designer]);
return (<div/>)
};
```

Comment: Why would `window.Designer` be the dependency?

Comment: You need to check if Designer exista ir It Will break, you can either use AND if or some, but you need to ser if It exists

Comment: The effect will still break if it doesn't exist. The value of `window.Designer` would then be `undefined`. Setting it as a dependency like that would only make the effect rerun if the value of `window.Designer` (not the `dataSource`) had changed from the last render of the component.